# Android - When I entered in EditText then value is not calculate in next EditText?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

amntpaid EditText value should be add in total EditText.But when I am running the below code, the addition is not happening.
  Check my code.

```
String subtotal=String.valueOf(amntpaid);
String total =String.valueOf(totamnt);
total = total+subtotal;
String ncr=total+"";
totalamt.setText(ncr);
```

Comment: @GiruBhai he is not able to add two EditText Values.

Comment: There are no integers, how will it calculate? Convert strings to integer then carry out addition. Right now you are just concatinating strings.

Comment: yes correct @Aniruddha  its concat only... how i will add ?

Comment: You have to post your full code to understand the question.

Comment: @17Coder Do you even know basics of Java? Or rather any programming language?

And as aniruddha has mentioned. Please post your full code and a better description to what you really wish to ask.

Comment: ONclick button ..That code i wrote in question ?

Comment: It's hard to understand what are those variables and from where you getting them. So better post related code.

Comment: @autocrat i know sir    its my mistake i ask question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:
do the sum of `amntpaid` and `totamnt` and store it in some `int` variable say `var`
like

```
var=Integer.parseInt(amntpaid.getText())+Integer.parseInt(totamnt.getText());
String value_to_be_set=String.valueOf(var);
totalamnt.setText(value_to_be_set);
```

where `totalamnt` is the `TextView` in which you want to set the value,and `amntpaid` and `totamnt`are your `EditText` from where you will get the entered input value.

Comment: shall i try this one -- 
'int  subtotal = Integer.parseInt(amntpaid);
int  total = Integer.parseInt(totamnt);
       
int var=subtotal + total;
       
String var1=String.valueOf(var);
totalamt.setText(var1);'

Comment: yes,but you just need to call getText() with amntpaid and totamnt like: amntpaid.getText() and totamnt.getText()

Comment: BEFORE I already call...                                                                                             String amntpaid=PaymentPaid.getText().toString();                                        String totamnt=totalamt.getText().toString();

Comment: then its fine, you can skip that getText()

Comment: int subtotal = Integer.parseInt(amntpaid.getText());                              Showing error -The method getText() is undefined for the type String

Comment: as you said that you have already used getText(),then you don't have to use it again

Comment: String amntpaid=PaymentPaid.getText().toString(); String totamnt=totalamt.getText().toString();                            int subtotal = Integer.parseInt(amntpaid); int total = Integer.parseInt(totamnt); int var=subtotal + total; String var1=String.valueOf(var); totalamt.setText(var1);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57144/discussion-between-17coder-and-nobalg).

Comment: Actully when i run .. i entered amount in paymentpaid editext 1000.But,when i click button entered amount should goes to totalamnt edittext......  its not work yet ?

Comment: you may be passing wrong references of the views of xml file,to your .java file....Please check that your findViewById() is picking up the reference of the right views and you are assigning them to the right references.

Comment: it will be easy for us,if you post the complete code of xml and .java file in your question

Answer (score 1):

This is just a sample and you have to modify it accordingly.

```
TextView resultTV;
EditText ed1, ed2;
Button add;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);

resultTV = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.your_tv_id)  // do the same for both edittexts and button


 add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

  String s1 = ed1.getText().toString();
  String s2 = ed2.getText().toString();
  if (!s1.trim().equals("") && !s2.trim().equals("")
  {
     int first = Integer.parseInt(s1);
     int second = Integer.parseInt(s2);
     int sum = first + second;
      resutTV.setText(sum + "");
  }
   else
   resultTV.setText("Please enter the values");
 }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding one string to another you need to TypeCast String data to Integer then only it will add

```
String subtotal = String.valueOf(amntpaid);
String total = String.valueOf(totamnt);
int sum = Integer.parseInt(total) + Integer.parseInt(subtotal);
totalamt.setText(sum + "");
```

Comment: @Aniruddha please justify your statement,i want to know the reason to make myself clear

Comment: @nobalG is this `total = Integet.parseInt(total) + Integet.parseInt(subtotal);` correct?. He is assigning string to int (which is not possible). He should have done `int grandTotal = Integet.parseInt(total) + Integet.parseInt(subtotal);` and then `total = grandTotal + "";`

Comment: The line `total = Integet.parseInt(total) + Integet.parseInt(subtotal);` is incorrect. Try something like `int totalAsInt = Integet.parseInt(total) + Integet.parseInt(subtotal);`

Comment: @Aniruddha i want to know about this one "Assigning int to string variable? Not good.".....why?

Comment: @nobalG I request you to please read the basics of java. You cannot store int value in string variable without typecasting it to string.

Comment: @henry000 : we both have done terrible mistake by copy pasting `total = Integet.parseInt(total) + Integet.parseInt(subtotal);` from answer. It should be **Integer.parseInt()** where he had written as **Integet.parseInt()**

Comment: @Aniruddha if you know about this then you should edit answer and make it correct instead of commenting.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add 2 strings, convert it to int first

```
String amount = amntpaid.getText().toString();
String total = totamnt.getText().toString();
int totalInt = Integer.parseInt(amount) + Integer.parseInt(total);
totalamt.setText("" + totalInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either

```
Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
```

or

```
Integer.valueOf(stringValue);
```

for those edittexts.

Try below code :

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString().trim());

int j = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString().trim());

int total = i + j;

String sum = total + "";
```

Comment: If your answer is same as the one of the answered then you should up vote it rather than giving the same answer. This is how stackoverflow works,.